# How to execute some shell script after opencv detect circle

Tags: c++, shell, ubuntu, opencv, codeblocks

How to execute some shell script (e.g 1.sh) after opencv detect circle?

I have used exec, it works but opencv program close after circle detected, and what I want is that the program didn't close until I press "q" key.

Here is my code:

```
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    IplImage  *img = 0;
    int       key = 0;
    CvFont font;

    cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.0,1.0,0,1,CV_AA);
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

    if ( !capture ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open initialize webcam!\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    img = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if (!img)
        exit(1);

    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), 8, 1 );
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    while( key != 'q' ) {
        img = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !img ) break;

        cvCvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        cvSmooth( gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5 );
        CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles( gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, >gray->height/40, 200, 100/*, 20, 100*/ );
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < circles->total; i++ )
        {
            float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );

            cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), cvRound(p[2]), >CV_RGB(50,255,30), 5, 8, 0 );
            cvPutText(img, "CIRCLE",cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]+45),cvRound(p[1]+45)), &font, >CV_RGB(50,10,255));

            if ( circles ) {
                execl("./1.sh", (char *)0);
            }

        }

        cvShowImage( "result", img );
        cvShowImage("gray", gray);
        key = cvWaitKey( 1 );

    }

    //    cvReleaseMemStorage(storage);
    //    cvReleaseImage(gray);
    cvDestroyAllWindows();
    cvDestroyWindow( "result" );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

    return 0;
}
```

I used codeblocks on ubuntu.

Comment: this question was asked here and it was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

After exec*, none of the code (in that process) will be reached.  You can fork, exec if you want the program to continue without waiting for the script to complete, otherwise add a wait.  Alternatively, you could use system or popen.

Examples:

example function to fork a command and wait:

```
#include <unistd.h>
/*as a macro*/
#define FORK_EXEC_WAIT(a) ({int s,p;if((p=fork())==0) \
{execvp(a[0],a);}else{while(wait(&s)!= p);}})
/*as a function*/
void fork_exec_wait(char** a) {
    int s,p;
    if((p=fork())==0){
        execvp(a[0],a);
    }else{
        while(wait(&s)!= p);
    }
}
```

to fork a command and continue

```
#include <unistd.h>
/*as a macro*/
#define FORK_EXEC(a)    ({if((fork())==0) execvp(a[0],a);})
/*as a function*/
void fork_exec(char** a) {
    int s,p;
    if((p=fork())==0)
        execvp(a[0],a);
}
```

the system command is ~ fork-exec-wait of "sh -c command args"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
system("command args");
```

the popen command is similar without the sh -c and will give you the output as a stream (think pipes, fifo, etc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *fp;
fp = popen("command args", "r");
...
pclose(fp);
```

Comment: Could you give me example or link to an example for exec with wait, or system or popen?

Comment: It is a char** (required by execvp)